# Load data dynamically with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a front-facing page using ajax to query a php script for server information.

The ajax call looks like:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "broker.php?action=getServers",
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        async: true,
        success: function(data) {
            $("table").append(data);
        }
});
```

The php page it queries echos out data as it comes in, but problem I'm having is the front-facing client only updates when the entire php script is finished rather than as the data is updated.

Is there a way I can make the ajax call update dynamically without having to manually query the page every x seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you are looking for is to implement your back-end and front-end with [web-socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), Ajax calls considered bad for performance if implemented it in a timeout/interval, check this [article](https://medium.com/system-design-blog/long-polling-vs-websockets-vs-server-sent-events-c43ba96df7c1) which compare **polling**, **long polling**, and **web-socket** with pros and cons, one of the advantages of web-socket is the performance, since the client will be notified by the server for the new updates instead of keep requesting changes.

check [PHP web socket documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.sockets.php) or you might go for PHP socket framework, for front-end [socket.io](https://socket.io) is one of the best front-end framework for sockets.